# Facebook Batch Request Single Completion Handler

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm using [Facebook's Batch Request API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/graph) to execute two separate requests at the same. The problem is that I can't seem to find a way to make it so both the requests come back in a single completion handler, instead of individually.

Is there not a way to do this?

Here's my code for what I'm currently doing:

```
let requestMe = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me",
    parameters: ["fields": "first_name, last_name, email, picture.width(1080).height(1080)"])
let requestThumbnailSizedPhoto = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me",
    parameters: ["fields": "picture.width(100).height(100)"])
let connection = FBSDKGraphRequestConnection()

connection.addRequest(requestMe) { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
    print("RequestMe complete")
}

connection.addRequest(requestThumbnailSizedPhoto) { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
    print("RequestThumbnailSizedPhoto complete")
}

connection.start()
```

Comment: Are you using any library to make normal http requests (like Alamofire)?

Comment: Yeah @jehna1. But these requests are being made through Facebook's FBSDKLoginKit SDK